# "Linux 3.19 and onwards, we should look at `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/`"?

Tags: power-management

https://askubuntu.com/a/309146/ says:

> Now we are encouraged to use -> `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0`.
>
> UPDATE: Linux 3.19 and onwards, we should look at the following
> directory -> `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/`

But on my NixOS:

```
$ uname -a
Linux o 5.19.0 #1-NixOS SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Jul 31 21:03:01 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status 
cat: /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status: No such file or directory
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status 
Discharging
```

So I was wondering what have happened?

Answer (score 1):

What has happened is that the edit is incorrect, or at least no longer correct (or perhaps, based on comments, specific to Arch Linux). [Batteries are counted from 0](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.8/source/drivers/acpi/sbs.c#L656), and identifiers can be skipped, so you’ll find `BAT0`, `BAT1` etc. depending on the system.

Thus you need to look at all battery directories, you can’t assume in general that any given system will have `BAT0` or `BAT1` etc. Some laptops even have multiple batteries and multiple `BAT?` directories.